# Understanding Objective-C scope issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Following is a snippet from a View Controller's implementation:

```
- (void)myOtherAwesomeMethod
{
    [self myAwesomeMethod]; // Compile ERROR here: Receiver type for instance message does not declare a method with selector
}

- (void)myAwesomeMethod
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Calling my awesome method...");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self myAwesomeMethod];

    [self myOtherAwesomeMethod];
}
```

I do not have `myAwesomeMethod` method declared in my header file, but why is it that I can call `myAwesomeMethod` in `viewDidLoad`, but not in `myOtherAwesomeMethod`?

I know the solution to this error is to declare the method in my header file, but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: where are you calling `-myOtherAwesomeMethod`?

Comment: Do you have a colon somewhere in your actual declaration or call?

Comment: I do not have any declaration for those 2 methods. But I am able to call `myAwesomeMethod` in `viewDidLoad`, but not in `myOtherAwesomeMethod`

Comment: I believe it's only warning, not error?

Comment: Also you can just NSLog the string, no need to format it.

Comment: @tia It is a compile error. I am using IOS 5 beta if that makes any difference.

Comment: @bipolarpants It is safer to put a format in. Here's an example where `NSLog` without format will break: `NSLog(@"I am just writing out valid format characters %@%d%f");` You are telling NSLog that there is an object, but you are not sending it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C, the rule is: *you got to declare it before you use it.*

Files are compiled from the top down. So here's what is happening in your code:

1. The compiler reads the @interface declaration for your class. Since you say neither method is declared in the header file, neither are in the symbol table yet.

   Your symbol table contains: nothing yet
2. The compiler reads the method definition for `myAwesomeMethod`. You haven't declared it yet, so it gets added to the symbol table. The body of the method contains a call to `NSLog`, which was declared long ago in a header provided to you by Apple.

   Your symbol table contains: `myAwesomeMethod`
3. The compiler reads the method definition for `viewDidLoad`; it was actually declared in a superclass's header file. The body of the method contains a call to `myAwesomeMethod`, which was found! It also contains a call to `myOtherAwesomeMethod`. Never heard of it!

   Now, this isn't an error, because it can still generate the code to make the call. It can infer argument types by how you use it (in this case, no arguments). It can't be sure of the return type, though (just because you don't use the return value doesn't mean there wasn't one). So it proceeds on the assumption that the call returns `id` and generates a warning.

   Your symbol table contains: `myAwesomeMethod`
4. Finally, the compiler reads the method definition for `myOtherAwesomeMethod`. It gets added to the symbol table. It compiles the body, which contains a call to `myAwesomeMethod`, which is in the table. All's well that ends well.

   At the end of the file, your symbol table contains: `myAwesomeMethod`, `myOtherAwesomeMethod`

If you're coming from a language like Java, this may seem silly, but that's because Java works differently than C. In Java, source code is compiled and linked in one step; you can't compile a class that refers to another class without having either the source code or class files available. That can be a hassle, but on the other hand, you never need about declarations apart from definitions.

In C, compiling and linking are different steps. The compiler just generates object code that refers to symbols that may be defined elsewhere; it uses declarations to make sure it generates the right code. The linker is responsible for matching up all those symbols with definitions in other libraries, static or dynamic.

In Objective-C, the linker doesn't actually know/care about Objective-C messages, because there is no way of knowing at compile-time/link-time whether an object can respond to a message. So it passes the buck to the runtime, which throws an exception if you get that far without a method definition.

Comment: Thanks @benzado, I found out that the order is the culprit. I don't really need to declare it anywhere, but the method definition need to come before it is being called. I'm accepting your answer anyway for the awesome explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I'm not sure why it works in viewDidLoad.

Notice that the error says "did not DECLARE" a method.  That's a hint that it's looking for a declaration (typically in a header)..ie a function prototype.

However, there's nothing that says a declaration has to be in a header.  YOu can put it at the top of the implementation file if you're not going to call that method from outside the file.